# Clarification on linear vs. quadratic convergence

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods

I'm having some trouble in understanding the different definitions for the rate of convergence of a sequence. I was playing around with following two functions, but even after experimenting for a while I'm still not really getting the point.

> Consider the two functions $f(x) = \frac{1}{2^x}$ and $g(x) = \frac{1}{2^{2^x}}$. For $x \to \infty$ both converge to $0$. It's easy to show that $f$ converges *linearly* with rate $1/2$, whereas $g$ converges *quadratically* to $0$.

Now, here's a plot I made with MATLAB. I plotted both functions to the same figure to compare them.

[image: MATLAB Plot]

We can see that $g$ is approaching its limit a little bit faster than $f$ (then again $g$ starts only from $1/2$ not $1$) , but the difference is not as dramatic as I was expecting. Even more confusing to me is the fact, that the graph of $f$ looks somewhat like a branch of a parabola whereas $g$ looks almost like a linear function (at least till about $x = 1.5$).

How can I make sense of this? Is there a way to plot these functions to exhibit the different rates of converges more clearly?

Comment: What about diminishing returns?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know anything about economics ;(

Comment: Could be interesting for this particular problem.
Since it isn't about a prove or a limit, it is about getting a feeling for the curves themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linear scale in your plot obscures the fact that $g(x)$ is *much* smaller than $f(x)$ as $x$ gets large.  For $x=5, f(x)=\frac 1{32}=0.03125, g(x)=\frac 1{2^{32}}=\frac 1{4294967296}\approx 2.33 \cdot 10^{-10}$  For larger $x$ the difference is even more pronounced.  I don't know what definitions of linear and quadratic convergence you are using.  I would have said that $f(x)$ converges exponentially to zero, which shows that it eventually becomes smaller than any inverse polynomial, and that $g(x)$ converges superexponentially to zero.

Here is a plot from Excel on a log scale.  You can see that $g(x) \ll f(x)$ rather quickly.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, for your answer! I'm using these definitions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_of_convergence#Convergence_speed_for_iterative_methods

Comment: Do you think it's maybe a good idea then to have a logarithmic axis?

Comment: Yes, if you make a sequence of $f(1), f(2), f(3),$ etc it would converge linearly by that definition. If you use a log axis you will see the difference more easily.  I will add one.